# How do I get android studio to work on dwm?

Tags: android-studio, x-dwm

When opening android studio , the starting screen comes up , but with no contents (just a grey window).

It works flawlessly when I change to kde via the option before login.

Even after pasting "export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1" into the terminal , it still does the same. (If it does not work , why should I put it in my startup code?). This was the fix ,that worked for most, but not for me.

I'm using manjaro.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use X11? I just put `export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPEATING=1` on my .xinitrc.

My .xinitrc looks like this:

```
pipewire &
pipewire-pulse &
dwmblocks &
autorandr m &
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
exec dwm
```